# iOS - video not playing

Tags: objective-c, ios, video

When I follow this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYXAHRvHbQE
It gives me an error on the [playercontroller release]; line, so I remove it, and then it gives me these errors when I try to run it

Here is the image: (it wont let me post it)
http://aftermathgame.webs.com/ss1.png

Comment: It also gives me this in the "build target">"all issues" window:

    http://pastebin.com/xpbncPBr

Comment: So I made a test app following this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Application

and it worked perfectly, so why does it not work on the app I want it to?

Answer (score 4):

If you simply must not add the header files only.

First, a framework must be added to your project.

Second, you should a following header. `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

refer a following process.

> 1. In Xcode, click your project file at the top of the Project Navigator.
> 2. Click 'YourProjectName' under "Targets"
> 3. Click the "Build Phases" tab.
> 4. Click the plus in the "Link Binary With Libraries" window.
> 5. Add the MediaPlayer.Framework library
> 6. Add `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlyer.h>`

[image]

Comment: I did that, and still no luck, should I put this: 
    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
in the header or implementation file? or both? i tried both but it still gives me the errors

Comment: here is my test project. refer a this project about linked frameworks. Will give you help. http://www.datafilehost.com/download-76ffa85e.html                 if you still don't understand. post your source code link. I'll be willing to assist you.

Comment: and refer a [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html) this is a apple sample code using a MediaPlayer frameworks

Comment: I am trying to make it fullscreen, like in the youtube app, not just like this:
http://aftermathgame.webs.com/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-15%20at%2011.04.45%20AM.png

Comment: In my project, look at the this code `player.view.frame = CGRectMake(35, 190, 245, 156)`; you are must re-set Frame. but i recommend apple Samplecode [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I dont understand how they did this, is this the easiest way to accomplish this? I want it so when you press a button in the storyboard, it plays a video in a new view.

Comment: I still think it is not importing the framework correctly. I tried it the other ways in the apple example, but it still did not work

Comment: Try reinstalling xcode after the complete removal. Something else seems to be a serious problem.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way? completely redownloading xcode will take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess this bit:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
```

... means you failed to link against the MediaPlayer framework.

Click on your project file in the navigator find the Linked Frameworks panel and add the the missing framework.

The semantic error you're also getting means you didn't declare your view controller as conforming to the AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol. (Add this in angle brackets `<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>` after the class declaration.)